# Store current page in session

Tags: php, html

On my page i have a footer file wich i include in every page of my website.
in the footer i want to save the current url to a session variable.

i have

```
$page = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
session_register("page");
echo "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SESSION['page'];
```

but it only stores 1 value and dosnt change if i go to another page.
i know there are other ways but i want is in session variable .

I hope someone can help me ?

i dont't know how to do it.

Comment: try declaring session_start() before.

Comment: `but it only stores 1 value` - what do you want it to do? Store the last e.g. 10 urls to have something like a bread crumb system?

Comment: i can use the information in the next page. so if some one loggs in or something he can be redirected to the page he was before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$page = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$_SESSION['page'] = $page;
echo "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SESSION['page'];
```

Use of [session_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) is DEPRECATED.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current page URL, PHP provides a superglobal variable `$_SERVER`. The `$_SERVER` is a built-in variable of PHP, which is used to get the current page URL. It is a superglobal variable, means it is always available in all scope.

If we want the full URL of the page, then we'll need to check the protocol (or scheme name), whether it is `https` or `http`. See the example below:

```
<?php  
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on')   
         $url = "https://";   
    else  
         $url = "http://";   
    // Append the host(domain name, ip) to the URL.   
    $url.= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];   
    
    // Append the requested resource location to the URL   
    $url.= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];    
    
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['page'] = $url;

    echo  $_SESSION['page'];  

  ?>
```